# The least value of $f(x)$=$\sqrt{x^2-2x+2}+\sqrt{x^2-4x+29}$

Tags: radicals, maxima-minima

If $m$ is the least value of $f(x)$=$\sqrt{x^2-2x+2}+\sqrt{x^2-4x+29}$, occur at $x = α$ , then $[m]+[α]$ is equal to (where [.] denotes greatest integer function)

(A)6

(B)7

(C)5

(D)4

My approach is as follow

$f(x)=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+1}+\sqrt{(x-2)^2+5^2}$

$\alpha$ lies between 1&2 and $m$ lies between 6 and 7 hence the answer is 7. I checked it and ur us correct. But solution is required

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus? if yes then this is very straight forward. differentiate the function once and set it equal to zero. the solution you get will be the the value of $\alpha$.

Comment: @Hersh You mean this question is lame?

Comment: Let $A=(1,1), B=(2,5)$ and $X(x,0)$ be any point of the x-axis. Then $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+1}=AX$ and  $\sqrt{(x-2)^2+5^2}=BX$. The problem becomes finding the minimum value of $AX+BX$ where $X$ is an arbitrary point on the $x-$axis. This can be solved geometrically.

Comment: @Hersh  Calculus is not needed.

Comment: @Li Kwok Keung You should transform your comment into an answer. I would be happy to upvote it.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung Yes I am aware that calculus is overkill, but just in case there weren't any other elegant approaches, its good to keep calculus as a back-up

Comment: @Hersh Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

In the figure, let $X(x,0)$ be any point on the $x$-axis.

Note that $AX=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+1}$ and $BX=\sqrt{(x-2)^2+5^2}$.

Therefore our job is to minimize $AX+BX$ where $X$ is an arbitrary point on the $x$-axis

Let $A'(1,-1)$ be the mirror image of $A(1,1)$ with respect to the $x$-axis.

From perpendicular bisector theorem,

$AX+XB=A'X+XB \ge A'B=AC+CB$

Thus the least value of $AX+XB$ is $A'B$. It is attained when $X=C$.

Since $A'B=\sqrt{(2-1)^2+(5+1)^2}=\sqrt{37}$

The least value of $f(x)$ is $\sqrt{37}$

Finally let $C=(\alpha, 0)$, then $\frac{0+1}{\alpha-1}=\frac{5+1}{2-1} \implies \alpha = \frac{7}{6}$

Comment: [+1] Very nice !

Answer (score 3):

By using the Cauchy Schwarz inequality, you can easily obtain:
$$\sqrt {a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{c^2+d^2}\ge \sqrt {(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2};$$

and equality holds if $\frac{a}{b}=\frac {c}{d}$. Now, take $a=x-1$, $c=2-x$, $b=1$, $d=5$. We get:

$$\sqrt {(x-1)^2+1^2}+\sqrt{(2-x)^2+5^2}\ge \sqrt {1^2+6^2}=\sqrt {37}\implies m=\sqrt {37}.$$

And,

$$\frac {x-1}{1}=\frac {2-x}{5}\implies a=\frac {7}{6}.$$

Comment: How did you use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in this solution, can you elaborate on this ?

Comment: @Nathalieissweetandawesome Raise both sides to the second power, then it is enough to show $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt {c^2+d^2}\ge ac+bd$.