# How to find min of $\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}+\sqrt{x^2-6x+10}$ without differentiation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, optimization, maxima-minima

I want to find minimum of $$\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}+\sqrt{x^2-6x+10}$$ without differentiation.
Although I did it with differentiation and $x=4/3$ then find $f(\frac 43)$ but I am unable to find the min without differentiation.
Implicit : I did this $$\frac{x^2+4x+8-(x^2-6x-10)}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}-\sqrt{x^2-6x+10}}$$but get nothing, because the $\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}+\sqrt{x^2-6x+10}>5$
now, If someone help me find it, or gives me a clue I appreciate this.

Comment: Hint: what are sum of distances of $(x,0)$ from $(3,1)$ and $(-2,-2)$?

Comment: In other words, forget Algebra and Calculus and use Geometry. Those square roots are some *distances*.

Comment: Another fact I think you'll need is that the distance from a point, to a wall, to another point, is minimized when the angle of incidence equals the angle of reflection.  This is equivalent to showing that the minimum of $$\left|\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} x \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right| + \left|\begin{bmatrix} -ak \\ bk \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} x \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right|$$ for $k > 0$ occurs at $x = 0$  This fact is used a bit in optics in physics.

Comment: It might be a duplicate. A very similar question at [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4570233/the-least-value-of-fx-sqrtx2-2x2-sqrtx2-4x29/4570242#4570242).

Comment: @DanielV: very cute..that was awesome approach

Comment: @achille hui: thanks a lot.  for obvious and clear you make for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, this is equivalent to minimizing the distance from $P=(3, 1)$ to the x-axis to $Q=(-2, 2)$.

The distance is minimized when the angle of incidence equals the angle of reflection*.  So if the points were of the form $(a, b)$ and $(-ak, bk)$, the reflection point that minimizes would be at the origin.  So when $P_x / P_y = -Q_x / Q_y$, the origin minimizes the distance.

So shift $P$ and $Q$ left so that they make equal angle with the origin and x-axis.

The shift amount, $t$, then must satisfy $$\frac{Px - t}{Py} = -\frac{Qx - t}{Qy}$$

So you get
$$t=\frac{P_xQ_y+P_yQ_x}{Py+Qy} = \frac{3 \times 2 + 1 \times -2}{1 + 2} = \frac{4}{3}$$

*Both points have to be on the same side of the x-axis for this to work.  If they are on opposite sides of the x-axis, this is equivalent to the concept "the shortest distance between two points is a straight line".